# Internet Explorer not displaying image loaded by CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

This is my HTML (the CSS is part of the HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <body>
        <div id='header'>

            <table id='headerBar'>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href ='#' id='homeIcon'></a></td>
                    <td><a href ='#' id='myProfileIcon'></a></td>
                    <td><a href ='#' id='settingsIcon'></a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<style>
    #homeIcon {
        content:url('shipping3.png');
    }
    #settingsIcon {
        content:url('shipping3.png');
    }
    #myProfileIcon {
        content:url('shipping3.png');
    }
</style>
```

When I open this file up in Google Chrome, it works perfectly fine and displays the 3 images. When I open it up in Internet Explorer, none of the 3 images are shown (It is just a blank page). Any idea why? (I tried viewing it from Internet Explorer 10, 9, 8, and 7. None display any of the 3 images).

Comment: Try changing the doctype to just `<!DOCTYPE html>`, IE7 and earlier do not support generated content: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/content

Comment: try using `#anchor-id { display:block; background:url('image.png'); }`

Comment: `content` is supposed to be used with pseudo-elements `before` or `after`, not on the element itself. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

Comment: Probably not the cause of the problem, but the HTML document is not well formed. There should be a `head` tag before the `body` tag, and the `style` tag should be inside the `head` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the content property is used with the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements to generate content in a document.

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/content

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
    #homeIcon::after {
        content:url('http://www.placehold.it/200x200');
    }
    #settingsIcon::after {
        content:url('http://www.placehold.it/200x200');
    }
    #myProfileIcon::after {
        content:url('http://www.placehold.it/200x200');
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='header'>

        <table id='headerBar'>
            <tr>
                <td><a href ='#' id='homeIcon'></a></td>
                <td><a href ='#' id='myProfileIcon'></a></td>
                <td><a href ='#' id='settingsIcon'></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w7c27/3/

Comment: Didn't you forgot some words in the first sentence?

Answer (score 2):

I have removed most of the code and left an example.

```
<td width="100" height="100" id='homeIcon'><a href ='#'></a></td>
<td><a href ='#' id='myProfileIcon'></a></td>
<td><a href ='#' id='settingsIcon'></a></td>

<style>
    #homeIcon {
       background:url("shipping3.png");
    }
...
</style>
```

The  tag my itself does not have a size, especially when empty. It is a no width/height container of nothing.

For backwards compatibility reasons the correct syntax for linking an image as a background is background:url("shipping3.png")

I have added the width and height of the  in line in order to observe easier where we specify them.

Comment: does this work in your Google Chrome and IE? Background doesn't seem to work in either of the two browsers for me, regardless of if I specify height / width or not. When I use background, nothing shows up. When I use content, it shows up in Chrome but not IE.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use background:url() to add image. As the a tag was empty so in IE it wasn't displaying the image. Here you go

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #homeIcon {
        background:url('shipping3.png');
        height:300px;
        width:100px;

    }
    #settingsIcon {
        background:url('shipping3.png');
    }
    #myProfileIcon {
        background:url('shipping3.png');
    }
</style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <table id='headerBar'>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href ="#" id="homeIcon">Lorem Ipsum</a></td>
                    <td><a href ="#" id="myProfileIcon"></a></td>
                    <td><a href ="#" id="settingsIcon"></a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hm, doing background:url('shipping3.png'); and giving it a width and height doesn't work for me in either Chrome or IE. Nothing shows up.. it works for you on your chrome? Even when there is no text inside the a tag?